# Cannot get frame or center for elements inside UIView that is inside UITableView

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, frame

I have an UITableView where first comes Table View Section following by UIView (bound to IBOutlet _myView) with some controls inside (e.g. UITextField, bound to IBOutlet _durationField). All this is done in the Storyboard. I want to move that _durationField dynamically, so I need to modify center or frame properties. However, this code inside viewDidLoad returns zero values:

```
CGRect durationRect = _durationField.frame;
```

whereas labels inside TableCell and _myView frame properties return real values, e.g. this doesn't return zeros:

```
CGRect viewRect = _myView.frame;
```

Also changing the frame property of _durationField doesn't reflect in the UI. Actually I get zero values for all controls inside _myView although they are properly bound to IBOutlet's in the code. Moreover, I can set _durationField.text in viewDidLoad and it works fine.

Any ideas? It looks like I'm missing something simple.

The first suggested solution with **viewWillLayoutSubviews** allows moving the element indeed but only after the view is rendered. So the user sees how it's moving. This is not a desirable behavior. I'd like to move the element dynamically before the view is rendered.

Answer (score -1):

In viewDidLoad, the UI is not laid out yet, you should move the code that adjusts the frame to **viewWillLayoutSubviews** (make sure you call the super class implementation first)

Comment: Thx! It solved the issue indeed. Although it's a bit doubtful to add custom code into the function that is being called several times during initial loading only (it's called three times for me actually).

Comment: Actually it did not solve the issue entirely. Now the element starts moving after the view is rendered. So the user sees how it moves.

Comment: If the view that has the controls is a TableViewCell, then you should be setting up the positioning in cellForRowAtIndexPath for the table. In normal cases viewWillLayoutSubviews will be called before the view is displayed (and also upon orientation change or other change that adjusts the parent view size)

Comment: No, the controls are inside simple UIView that is itself inside UITableView. BTW, there are also controls inside UITableView but there is no issue with them, I can get center and frame values in viewDidLoad. As I said, viewWillLayoutSubviews is being called three times in a row for me. The first time center and frame have zero values, the second and third time non-zero. The second time modification of center doesn't help, the third time viewWillLayoutSubviews is called after UI is rendered. As a result, this last third call moves my controls.

Comment: You could try your layout in viewWillAppear, but generally in the latest iOS, viewWillLayoutSubviews is generally best (even if you are getting multiples).  You could also try in viewDidLayoutSubviews, but not sure if that would make a difference.

Comment: Hm, viewWillAppear is called once, frame and center are zeros. However, viewDidLayoutSubviews is called twice - first time zeros, second time non-zeros. The second time I update center, the element moves but I see it again! May it be an issue of Simulator only?